# Copy Artifacts in Jenkins does not copy right

Tags: jenkins, copy, artifacts

I am having issues time to time with my builds when copying artifacts from one job to another during build time. Artifacts need to be copied due to dependency issue and what happens is that sometimes the copying does it right and sometimes it misses some files.

I have run 2 builds on same source, in one build it copied 849 artifacts from another project and
in the next build it copied only 722 artifacts and nothing has changed in between.

I am using Copy Artifacts plug-in version 1.21.

Question: Is there any way to make a verbose log of copying so I can trace what files are being copied?
And is there Any other way to get aware of this during build time? I got noticed this problem when QA created a bug that some functionalists are not working in the build and that was due to the files missing.

Any help, suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing a similar problem.